# redirect to https www htaccess on EC2

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-ec2

I have added `.htaccess` to force redirect to https www like as below.

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

The website  is redirecting and says 
  "**This webpage has a redirect loop**". Why it happens
I am using amazon EC2 Server with loadbalancer.

Comment: Check the error logs

Comment: What about using `RewriteRule ^http:(.*)$ https://www.mysite.co.uk/$1 [R,L]`?

Comment: @alk This error only occure with amazon loadbalancer